# Angular display a rounded number but preserve full precision otherwise

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a simple component with a `readonly` field containing output values taken from an ngModel

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myObject.response.value" readonly/>
```

The value returned is always in full precision for example "1.12318995165161..." But for display it is needed to be rounded to 2 decimal places "1.12".

Using PrimeNG's p-InputNumber I can round the value to 2 decimal places but the precision is lost in the process.

```
<p-inputNumber [(ngModel)]="myObject.response.value" [maxFractionDigits]="2" readyonly></p-inputNumber>
```

What I hope to achieve is even after the display is formatted to 2 decimal places, **I require the values to maintain full precision when copied out through a CTRL-C operation** How can I achieve this in angular? Thank you.

Comment: And what is expected behavior if value is changed? for eg. `1.12318995165161` => displayed value `1.12`, and then value changed to `1.13`, then what is expected value?

Comment: if the returned value is 1.13, the display and raw value would expect to be 1.13. What I wish to achieve is to preserve the raw value when I want to copy its value but display a rounded value when displayed to the user.

Comment: @James Your question is lacking information, like: 1. Are these read-only input fields or can you edit them as well? And what's the expected behavior when editing? 2. Copied out how? By selecting the value and pressing Ctrl + C? By pressing a "Copy" button?

Comment: Hi Vasileios, I have provided some additional context on the behavior, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to display the rounded number using PrimeNg, a pipe or whatsoever, and then listen to the copy event to write the content you want to the clipboard.

```html
<p-inputNumber [(ngModel)]="myObject.response.value" [maxFractionDigits]="2" readyonly (copy)="handleCopy()"></p-inputNumber>
```

```
handleCopy() {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.myObject.response.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `input` is `readonly` and you're not going to edit it, you don't have to use 2-way-binding. Also, there's no need to use PrimeNG.

Instead you can bind to the `value` attribute and use the [decimal](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#usage-notes) pipe to fix the precision like this:

```
<input [value]="this.myObject.response.value | number: '1.2-2'" (copy)="onCopy()" readonly />
```

And in your component `.ts` file you can handle the copying event like this:

```
public onCopy(): void {
   navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.myObject.response.value);
}
```